# Search engine console Click vs Analytic Session

Tags: google, google-analytics, google-search-console

I am facing an issue. In my analytic account, there is variation between clicks and session. For a month there are 841 clicks but no of sessions are only 393. Can someone please explain the reason?

Answer (score 1):

There's a large number of possible reasons for this. Here's a few possible factors:

- All stats are estimated unless you're on Analytics Premium and pulling the full data. Google takes a sample and extrapolates.
- It's possible to invalidate records for a count if they have an unset field. Perhaps there were 841 aggregated clicks but one of the criteria for a valid session is missing, causing sessions to be dropped for the report count.
- Ad blockers can prevent collects containing all information.
- Client is bouncing before a pageview is registered. This produces a 'click' action from the origin but fails to register a session at the destination.
- There's cookie blocking in play and the link is changing domains.
- The user is using a bookmark. This can count as a click but not cause a new session.

It's worth checking your network output in Chrome developer console. Look at the 'collect' calls that Analytics makes and go through the click/view process a few times.